# Insert data depends on input date

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, sql

i have table row(january to december) but im not yet implementing it .

i got this code:

```
<input type="date" name="batchnum" required="">

mysqli_query($connections, 
  "INSERT INTO receiving (
     batchnum, description, qtyin, unit, stkonhand,
     status, purpose, supplier, address, num,
     dr, inv, price, totalprice, receivedby, 
     notedby)
   VALUES(
     '$db_batchnum','$db_description','$db_qtyin','$db_unit','$db_stkonhand',
     '$db_status','$db_purpose','$db_supplier','$db_address','$db_num',
     '$db_dr', $db_inv','$db_price','$db_totalprice','$db_receivedby',
     '$db_notedby')");
```

i want this datas to be inserted on month base on the month they pick . thanks im just a newbie i really need help so i can sort and get them by month.

Comment: Please do not post your question title in ALL CAPS. There is no need to shout here to get attention. People will see your question and answer it if they can without the need to SHOUT. Thanks.

Comment: did i shout ? where is the all caps then ?

Comment: In the title before I edited it, as you can see in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50614794/revisions).

Comment: ok sir thank you and im sorry i didnt mean it .

Comment: Can you provide the rest of your `<form>` and `php` code?
I'm assuming you have a `<select>` dropdown or a date picker where they pick the date?
I noticed you tagged "jquery" -  is there any javascript handling the form submit already?

Comment: batchum as a date value??? weird. Anyway you can try adding to 
 your `january to december` field : MONTH({$batchnum})

Comment: batchnum is just a name of database but it is date . i dont have script that handles the form or the batchnum

Comment: i think i want that if the batchnum detect that date is 12/31/2018 it will insert into table december base on the input date

Comment: Get the month part of your selected date and do your process based on that. Do you want the data to be inserted when they select a date (JS) or when they select a date and click the submit button (PHP)?

Comment: yes sir base on the month in the selected date

Comment: click submit button (php) @hungrykoala